# XHTML 1.0 Strict Error : <select name="url" onchange="document.location.href = this.value">

Tags: javascript, xhtml, onchange, w3c, validation

The W3C returns an error on my xHTML (1.0 strict) code concerning this select form (I use it for a dropdown navigation menu) :

```
<select name="url" onchange="document.location.href = this.value>
```

here is the error message :

> document type does not allow element "select" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag
>    
>   The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.
>   One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "< p>" or "") inside an inline element (such as "", "", or "").

Any clue on how should I write it to be OK with the W3C ?

Thank you !

Comment: It would help if you showed the HTML markup around the element.

Comment: Doesn't that very long message answer your question?

Comment: Please don't do that: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking around the internet, it sounds like `<Select>` is an inline element that needs to be within a block element like `<p>` or `<div>`. See the example [here](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/select/).

Comment: Thanks Jeff I added <p></p> around the <select></select> and now W3C says that it's fine !

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in there

> document type does not allow element "select" here; missing one of
>   "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address",
>   "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag The mentioned element is not
>   allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other
>   mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and
>   can contain the element mentioned. **This might mean that you need a
>   containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a
>   previous element.** One possible cause for this message is that you have
>   attempted to put a block-level element (such as "< p>" or "") inside
>   an inline element (such as "", "", or "").

We can not give you a better answer since your code you gave is just the select.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit of the error message is the most important:

> document type does not allow element "select" here;

Move the `<select>` element to somewhere that it is allowed.

It is hard to suggest where that might be as you didn't give any details about where "here" is.